# Magento 2: Difference between adding object in Constructor and adding via object Manager?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, What is the main difference between adding an object in Constructor and adding via object Manager?

Adding an object in Constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor $processor
){
    $this->_processor = $processor;
}
```

Adding via Object Manager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->create('Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is when adding an object in Constructor,the object is  instantiates at the beginning of the bootstrapping process by the Object Manager itself. Whereas Adding via Object Manager the object is instantiates only on request.

The better process is adding an object in Constructor because the object instantiation is completely handled by Framework, you no need to do anything after that and it can be used throughout the class. for more [please read this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html).

Comment: Instead of loading the object in the constructor, Can I just call the object using object manager whenever it's needed?

Comment: it will works but better way to inject the dependent class in the constructor.

Comment: why is it better? Can you please explain it briefly?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check.